# Calculating IDF (as in TF-IDF) when testing?

Tags: text, classification, information-retrieval, tf-idf

As I understand it, IDF is used to calculate how many documents have the term (sort of just the idea). You can calculate IDF (along with TF) in the training set since you have all the documents beforehand. But what if I don't have the test set beforehand and I'm getting test documents in a sequential manner (like from a web crawler), then how am I going to calculate the IDF for words in a document when it comes to testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this state if your dataset is big enough you could using just training set for IDF. in the test phase if the new term be in train set use the IDF of training and if the term is new use the number of train set documents for calculate IDF.
For some purposes you could use smoothing methods for having better results.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me. However, I am wondering if there is any paper or article to which you can refer? AND, I am wondering if there is any library that we can use it for this matter?

Comment: This is my edited comment: This answer partly makes sense to me. However, I am wondering if there is any paper or article to which you can refer? The question is that, lets say you have already trained your model, once you have a new word in test doc, even if you can calculate the IDF for that word using your big dataset, but you`re still gonna have different number of features in training and testing sets and it is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you only perform tests after indexing/crawling a whole bunch of documents you can calculate IDF after the crawling is done. You don't have to calculate IDF when you encounter a new document or a new term. You can calculate it on-the-fly when you need it to do some TD-IDF or other calculation.

If that is not enough, for some reason, you can still use the IDF of another document dataset, preferably with the same type of documents.

Comment: "If you only perform tests after indexing/crawling a whole bunch of documents" - not really. when I receive a page by the crawler, I have to decide whether that page is relevant or irrelevant at that moment. As you mentioned calculating IDF of another document dataset is the practice in such a situation?